# Serialize an array to store it versus create a specific table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, backend

I want know what solution is more efficient (or know another better solution of course). If I have a website where any user can leave a comment for each post, what will be the better solution?

> Serialize an array with all comments for that post in a column of database (I don't know if it is possible that two users leaving a comment at the same time can lead to data loss)

Or maybe is better the following:

> Creating a specific table called comments, where I have an unique id for each post and other unique id for each username

I read that some people don't like use the serialize function, but I don't know if it is a good idea or not their use

Comment: Create a table. It's better scalable and maintainable than using a serialized array.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply @CharlotteDunois Do you think that the efficiency of the database is maintained with two ids for each row? Or can I do another thing to improve the efficiency?

Comment: Specific table with unique ids is always the better way.

Comment: Tables are the better route.  Serializing is best when there are large amounts of data for a single record and when you're not asking for the data constantly.

Comment: Okay, perfect. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table. Comments table with relation to your Posts And no alternatives for it.
Create, update, delete actions for specific comment and search at all becomes painful using serialization into single field.